# Standard Gumbel distribution — Wikipedia vs. Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Standard_Gumbel_distribution), the PDF of the standard Gumbel distribution is

$\qquad f(x) = e^{-(x+e^{-x})}$

whereas in Mathematica I obtain

```
PDF[GumbelDistribution[0, 1], x]
```

> `E^(-E^x+x)`

which is not the same thing.

So which one is correct?

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation? Right there, first section:"...The asymptotic distribution of the maximum value, also sometimes called a Gumbel distribution, is implemented in the Wolfram Language as ExtremeValueDistribution...".

Comment: More generally, `PDF[GumbelDistribution[a, b], x] == 
  PDF[ExtremeValueDistribution[-a, b], -x] // Simplify` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Ok I see. But then which distribution is the one called 'Gumbel' in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

According to Section 6 of the Wikipedia article that you link to, the Mathematica distribution equivalent to the Gumbel distribution defined in the article is

```
PDF[GumbelDistribution[0, 1], -x]
```

which indeed gives

```
E^(-E^(-x) - x)
```

in agreement to the Wikipedia article's definition.